# Eval and Bind doesn't work for dropdownlist in repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Am having a DropDownlist inside a repeater control.Initially the dropdown list should have the value from the database.And in my case its the userStatus property of my object.Eval and Bind is not working in this and When i use

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Enabled="true" DataSource='<%#Eval("userStatus") %>'  CssClass="box1" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
```

am getting the value of dropdown as characters.Suppose if the value is Admin its coming as A d m i n as each option.Is there any way to do it apart from the code behind page.

Answer (score 1):

userStatusplease set "DataTextField" and "DataValueField" of dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Enabled="true" DataSource='<%# (string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "userStatus") %>' CssClass="box1" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
```

Comment: I tried including both but its showing the first listitem in my dropdown list as the default value for all my dropdown controls

Comment: Am having the same problem,if its Admin then am getting each character of the string as an option